# Vitest describe.concurrent is failed

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, vitest

need a help. I want to run parallel test on my React propject by using Vitest, but `describe.concurrent` is failing every test where using `vi.fn()` and check this functions.

Example:

```
describe.concurrent('Button component', () => {
    test('init render', async ({ expect }) => {
        render(<Button data-testid="add-button" />)
        expect(screen.getByTestId('add-button')).toBeInTheDocument()
    })

    test('onClick has been called once', async ({ expect }) => {
        const onClickMockFunc = vi.fn()
        render(<Button onClick={onClickMockFunc} data-testid="add-button" />)

        await userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('add-button'))
        expect(onClickMockFunc).toHaveBeenCalledOnce() // trouble is here
    })

    test('to have correct text', async ({ expect }) => {
        render(<Button data-testid="add-button">Test btn</AddButton>)
        expect(screen.getByText('Test btn')).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
})
```

how can I speed up the execution of tests? And how can I fix the error with describe.concurrent?